# How to import this link by importxml in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, fetch, google-sheets-formula

I think the xpath is not standard but I do not know how to fetch data from this dam site

IMPORTXML("http://www.tsetmc.com/loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=36773155987365094#","/html/body/div[4]/form/div[3]/div[9]/span/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY3ru.jpg)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY3ru.jpg)
")

[image]

[image]

Comment: What part of website are you trying to fetch? Could you provide screenshot?

Comment: Can you show, which data do you want to import?

Comment: I have added the screen of where I want. firstly you have to click on the fist screen (a bottom on the right side) and then extract the table shown. please look at the screen shots step by step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As on this page you need to click on a tab to open what you want, it would be impossible to go through it.

So I had to open Google's Dev Tools, under *Network* and selected *Fetch/XHR*:

[image]

After that, I copied the text `شركت سرمايه گذاري البرز-سهامي عام-`, press `CONTROL + F` to search all url's and searched the text, it was found in a single instance:

http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?Partree=15131T&c=IRO3ETLZ0007

Equipped with this url, when opening it, it is fixedly only that tab:

[image]

Well, then the hardest part is gone, now just create the desired path:

```
=IMPORTXML(
           "http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?Partree=15131T&c=IRO3ETLZ0007",
           "//tr[@class='sh']"
          )
```

Which resulted in what you want:

[image]